# How can I set the TextColor of a TextAppearanceSpan?

Tags: android

I currently able to create a Medium size TextAppearanceSpan, But how can I set the text color to a specified RBG color (say #c71585)?

```
new TextAppearanceSpan(context, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);
```

I see there is a constructor for

```
public TextAppearanceSpan(Context context, int appearance,
                          int colorList) {
```

But what is the int for colorList? Is there any example for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not use a `TextAppearanceSpan` with no `colorList`, in conjunction with a [`ForegroundColorSpan`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ForegroundColorSpan.html)?

Comment: How can I use TextAppearanceSpan in conjunction with ForegroundColorSpan. I tired spannableStrBuilder.setSpan(TextAppearanceSpan, start end); spannableStrBuilder.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan, start end);
I only see the color is changed.

Comment: Hm, let me try and get back to you. I guess my assumption that it would work may have been faulty.

Comment: I think I am wrong. I see the color now, if I do this
= new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(0, 80, 0));

but it won't work if i do new ForegroundColorSpan(R.colors.mycolor) and I put <color name="mycolor">#ffff0080</color>

Comment: I have resolved it. I need to do new ForegroundColorSpan(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.mycolor))

Sorry for the false alarm

Answer (score 0):

According to the Docs:

`public TextAppearanceSpan (Context context, int appearance, int colorList)`

> Uses the specified TextAppearance
>   resource to determine the text
>   appearance, and the specified text
>   color resource to determine the color.
>   The appearance should be, for example,
>   `android.R.style.TextAppearance_Small`,
>   and the colorList should be, for
>   example,
>   `android.R.styleable.Theme_textColorDim`.

Comment: Thank you. I read that. But how can I put my color say #c71585 to android.R.styleable.Theme_textColorDim?

Answer (score 0):

sry, i can't add a comment, the above statement isn't totally correct...
accessing the color via:

**new ForegroundColorSpan(R.color.color_name,..)**

not R.colors (as above)

scheme of **colors.xml**

> < resources >
>
> ```
> < color name="bright_green">#44f014< /color>
> ```
>
> < /resources >

have fun